# Making user-defined literals with pre-processor

Tags: c++, c++11, literals

I'm trying to write a macro to create user-defined literals out of a regular string literals. The following two lines should create the token `"foobar"_literal`:

```
#define AS_LITERAL(TEXT) TEXT ## _literal
AS_LITERAL("foobar");
```

However, the pre-processor of *GCC-4.7* reports the following error:

```
error: pasting ""foobar"" and "_literal" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

How to do that correctly?

Comment: Is `"foobar"_literal` valid C?

Comment: Just a guess, but possibly the C-string literal and your defined name are seen as 2 different tokens by the compiler, so try removing the `##`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Well, yes, IMHO.  If the goal is flawed, then the question probably is too...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Is valid C++11.

Comment: @lvella: Ah, I misread; I had thought this was tagged C.  My mistake!

Comment: +1 by the way, this is a valid question. I suspect most people here failed to realise that it was about C++11.

Comment: If you are going to wrap the literal in `AS_LITERAL()` anyway, than I think you can do this without using C++11 features with a simple function of prototype `AS_LITERAL(const char*)`.  What is the point of going from preprocessor to `operator""`?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: With user-defined literals, the length of the string is available at compile-time. In most cases, I can simply use the suffix for the user-defined literal. But I also want to use the compile-time length for macros like `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with an appropriately defined `operator "" _literal` (using GCC 4.7 as well):

```
#include <cstdlib>

#define AS_LITERAL(TEXT) TEXT ## _literal

constexpr int operator "" _literal(char const*, std::size_t) { return 0; }

int main() {
    int x = AS_LITERAL("abc");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The important information was, that it should work with GCC-4.7. After checking again, I noticed that I forgot to use the command-line option `-std=c++11`.

Comment: I tried it here with GCC 4.6, and it failed to compile. It seems that OP's problem is just lack of support for the feature in his compiler.

Comment: user-defined literal support was added in GCC 4.7